# Etsy api OAuth2 using httr oauth2.0_token

Tags: r, rest, oauth-2.0, httr, etsy

I am trying to use the etsy API which requires both an [API key and oauth2 authentication](https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#tag/Ledger-Entry). The [example authentication URL that they provide in the docs](https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/tutorials/quickstart/#start-with-a-simple-express-server-application) looks like this:

```
https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect?
  response_type=code&
  redirect_uri=http://localhost:3003/oauth/redirect&
  scope=email_r&
  client_id=1aa2bb33c44d55eeeeee6fff&
  state=superstring&
  code_challenge=DSWlW2Abh-cf8CeLL8-g3hQ2WQyYdKyiu83u_s7nRhI&
  code_challenge_method=S256
```

Cobbling together what I can from tutorials for the [r httr package](https://github.com/r-lib/httr) I have the following code:

```
shopID <- '111111' # not real values
etsy_keystring <- 'foobar' 
etsy_shared_secret <- 'foobarbaz' 

options(httr_oob_default=TRUE)
etsy_endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect",
           access = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/public/oauth/token")
etsyApp <- oauth_app("etsyApp", 
                 key = etsy_keystring, 
                 secret = etsy_shared_secret,
                 redirect_uri = "http://localhost:1410")
oauth2.0_token(endpoint = etsy_endpoint, 
           app = etsyApp, 
           scope = 'billing_r', 
           oob_value = "http://localhost:1410")
```

which opens the browser to the following url:

```
https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect?
  client_id=foobar&
  scope=billing_r&
  redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1410&
  response_type=code
```

Which etsy gives an error page for. What I think I am missing, is a way to generate PKCE tokens. Is this possible with httr? Or am I missing something completely obvious.

Comment: I know nothing about the httr library, but OAuth2 server should give you a meaningful error message if your auth URL is not complete or if it's invalid. Do you get some hints from Etsy about why they respond with error? PKCE is required for "public clients" (such as browser app or mobile app). If your application runs in a safe environment and you have a client_secret, PKCE is usually optional. PKCE is a kind of one time password.

Comment: The Etsy error page just says that the url is not valid. Nothing more informative.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not so far. I'll probably give up and switch to python instead.

Comment: Make sure that your call back URL is defined exactly as is on your Etsy account - Go to https://www.etsy.com/developers, then click edit app and click on Edit Your callback URLs.

Comment: For me I get a javascript validation error after the user has authorised my app, and hence when I'm posting the request (successfully) via Postman.  Alas, I'm now having trouble requesting a refreshed token, as the response is always Missing grant_type even though I've followed the guidelines on their docs: https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/essentials/authentication#requesting-a-refresh-oauth-token